# Wicket - question marks when inserting cyrillic characters to the database

Tags: database, wicket

I am using wicket, spring and mysql. When I try to insert cyrilic characters to the database instead of the characters I see question marks ('?????').

When I use the i18n files I don't have such kind of problem. Also, when inserting characters from other place (i.e. mysql workbench) there is no problem. In other words, the problem is not in the database. The database and my html documents are in utf-8.

Could you please help me solve this problem.

Cheers!
Nikolay

Comment: Try to add `&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to your JDBC URL.

Comment: This also didn't help :(.

Answer (score 1):

Wicket has two more encoding-related settings, try this (in you `Application` initialization):

[`getMarkupSettings()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#getMarkupSettings%28%29).[`setDefaultMarkupEncoding("utf-8")`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/settings/IMarkupSettings.html#setDefaultMarkupEncoding%28java.lang.String%29);

[`getRequestCycleSettings()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#getRequestCycleSettings%28%29).[`setResponseRequestEncoding("utf-8")`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/settings/IRequestCycleSettings.html#setResponseRequestEncoding%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: That didn't help. This is a very shitty problem. When I print the input data of the user in the console, everything is fine but the result is the same. Which makes me think that the problem is in the database. But I also tryed to insert data from phpmyadmin (another web client) and everything is fine, which makes me think that the problem is in wicket. Also, when I hardcode data in my code it appears again as question marks in the database. And that again turns me to the database. I cannot catch the problem. It is very confusing.

Comment: Also, I have another project on Cloud Foundry with the same configurations in the database, wicket, spring everywhere, and there this problem doesn't exist :(.

Comment: I found the problem. I had to change the default character encoding of mysql to utf8. I didn't have this problem and I don't know how this happened, but I created admin panel in mysql workbench and maybe it has overriden my default settings. 

Thank you all guys! I really appreciate your efforts to help me!